# Resizing a QTableWidget column based on a single row rather than with `resizeColumnsToContents`

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, pyside6

I am using PySide6 and have a `QTableWidget` with many rows, and `resizeColumnsToContents` is very slow. I only need to resize the columns based on the width of a particular row. Presumably `resizeColumnsToContents` is searching for the widest row in the column, then updating with that, and so could be sped up by directly telling with which row to resize on.

I cannot find such a function in the API, so want to implement this using `columnResized` (first, finding the required width from the text of the widest row, then setting the column to this width). However, I cannot figure out how to calculate the required column size based on the text that I have. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand how your proposal would speed up anything: in order to find "the required width from the text of the widest row" you would need to iterate through all rows anyway, which is what `resizeColumnsToContents()` does in the first place (and it also does it on the C++ side, so it's even faster than doing it in python). It's also unclear how you expect to use `columnResized()`, since it's not virtual and thus cannot be overridden.

Comment: thanks @musicamante for your response, on the first point I may not have been clear, I know already the widest row and so will not need to iterate through all rows. I just need to resize the column based on the known string length of the  widest row. On the second point I may have misunderstood `columnResized`. Can you not call `my_qtablewidget.columnResized(old_val, new_val)` to perform the resize?

Comment: Will overriding [`QTableView::sizeHintForColumn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#sizeHintForColumn) to return a constant (or cached) value not give you what you want?  Combine that with [`setResizeContentsPrecision(0)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setResizeContentsPrecision) to limit the number or rows considered when calculating the required column width.

Comment: @Joseph To get the width of the string use: `tableWidget.fontMetrics().boundingRect(string).width()`. It's unnecessary and wrong to use `columnResized`, which is a protected slot. Just set the resize-mode to either `Interactive` or `Fixed` and use e.g. `tableWidget.setColumnWidth()` instead.

Comment: @Joseph How do you know which is the "widest row"? Assuming that you're using the table to display alphanumeric values, how are you computing the widths? Note that: 1. unless you're using a fixed-width font, you cannot base the width on the string length (in most fonts, "W" is much larger than "iii"), so you must use font metrics; 2. you must consider item margins; 3. "widest row" is ambiguous; for example, a table with 2 rows and 10 columns, the former with "WW" for each item, the latter with "i" for 9 items and "WWW" for the last, will give the first row as the widest, but the last »

Comment: @Joseph » column would be the widest based on the *second* row. All that brings back to the original question, but in a more correct way: how do you know which row has the widest content for a specific column? Note that `columnResized()` is a slot mainly used by headers (when the column is *resized*, note the past tense), so using it is inappropriate for this purpose. Use [`setColumnWidth()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#setColumnWidth) instead.